# time() returns different timestamps based on server

Tags: php, unix, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I searched now for many hours, it seem's like nobody got that problem before.

I run a script, which writes the current timestamp into a database, on two servers. Both have the same os, software, ... and the same timezone.

Now I found out, that the diff between some timestamps and the current time() is a negative number (yes, the calculation is correct: `time() - $older_timestamp`)

I dumped time() on both servers, the result: it differs by exactly one hour.
Check it out:

- [time() on server #1: -1 hour](http://100prorealty.de/unixtime.php)
- [time() on server #2: correct timestamp](http://brainedia1.de/maklerprojekt/unixtime.php)

Since time() should be always UTC-based, I can not explain, how this happens.

Does someone have any idea?

Greetings from Aachen

Comment: Have you checked that actual time on each server? While time will always ignore timezone (and use UTC), if the time on the server is incorrect, so will your results on that server.

Comment: Difference between BIOS and OS time: http://www.overclock.net/t/839485/bios-time-correct-os-time-not

Comment: So tell us, what have done to fix it?

Comment: I setup ntpd to sync with the same timeserver - thanks to everyone! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently server one and server two are set to different times. Check **BIOS** and your **servers' OS** time.

Comment: Yes it was. Usind ntpd to sync both servers with the same timeserver fixed it.

Comment: Yes, heard of this problem! :) Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

To add to the merry fest, I give you another option.

The OS' Time-Zone might be set incorrectly. If both clocks show the same time but one server thinks it is in London while the other thinks it is in Aachen, the UTC time returned from the system call will differ by one hour.

If you would however install say `NTPD` none of this would happen. (usually)

Comment: I don't know whether it was the timezone of the system. I used ntpd to sync both servers with the same timeserver.

Comment: @Robert Unix systems usually support the console command `date` which prints the current system time, plus time zone, for future reference maybe.

Comment: thanks, I absolutely didn't think of the system's time. I used many servers and never had problems. Additionally both servers are rented at the same company with the same standard system installation.

Comment: @Robert During installation you may get asked whether the system time represents GMT or local time. If the one setting it up chose the wrong one due to slight, it could easily turn out that way

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by the timezone being incorrectly set in the `php.ini` for Apache. Check the `php.ini` file for `date.timezone =` and change it to your timezone. A list of PHP timezones can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

For example:

```
date.timezone = 'America/Chicago'
```

You may also be able to use an [`ini_set`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) if you cannot edit the `php.ini` file directly.

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Chicago');
```