# Why time() function returns different values on different servers?

Tags: php, time

When I write this line of code on local, the output will be this:

```
echo time(); // 1464605083
```

And when I write in on the [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/kLCKY) *(online PHP shell)* the output will be this:

```
echo time(); // 1339412843
```

As you see there is a huge different between those outputs. What's wrong? And how can I sync them?

---

**Note:** I'm using Xampp on my local.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978567/time-returns-different-timestamps-based-on-server) seems to be very similar to your current issue.

Comment: @DainisAbols I think so, but how can I change timezone on my local? Is that depend on my OS *(windows)* or PHP has its own timezone?

Comment: `05/30/2016 @ 10:44am (UTC)` vs `06/11/2012 @ 11:07am (UTC)` doesn't look like a timezone issue. Did you check the system dates on both machines?

Comment: Far easier to work with DateTime objects rather than unix timestamps, DateTime objects incorporate the timezone in a way that's easier to manage

Comment: IT seemd that `time` ignores the timezone settings, but you need to check the actual time on both servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That timezone will be vary according to the servers you are using. If you want to use same timezone in all your server. Use

`date_default_timezone_set('timezonename')`

Comment: Welcome. If it was helpfull. Mark as right answer. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

If the time you got back from the code is not the right time, it's probably because your server is in another country or set up for a different timezone.

So, if you need the time to be correct according to a specific location, you can set a timezone to use.

The example below sets the timezone to "America/New_York", then outputs the current time in the specified format:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

use timezone i hope it's work ...

```
<?php 
 date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
echo $date= time() ;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The webserver where you are testing this has a completely off system time set.

If you look at the date of your test script (right next to the title field) you'll see that it has been saved at `@ Mon Jun 11 2012 11:07:23`.

Your timestamp `1339412843` translates to `06/11/2012 @ 11:07am (UTC)`.

So, the server time is just wrong. Test your script someplace else if time is critical.

Comment: I see, but how can I set a default for my PHP? in which file of configuration? *php.ini*?